# How to set a property of a different control from a style setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `ListView` and inside this another `ListView`. Whenever I select an item in a child `ListView` I want the parent of that to be selected in the parent `ListView`. Example:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Parent ListView ItemsTemplate... Incomplete -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="parentItemTemplate">
            <!-- Child ListView -->
            <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding ChildSelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding WhateverInParent}">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <!-- This is what I want to do, but ofc this doesn't work because it produces a compile error saying can't set TargetName in a setter -->
                            <Setter TargetName="parent" Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsTemplate="{StaticResource parentItemTemplate}" x:Name="parent" SelectedItem="{Binding ParentSelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Whatever}"/>
</Window>
```

How do I get this done? Would prefer it to be in XAML.

Comment: cannot do via style..but why do you want to do this? and ListView does not have IsSelected property. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @nit: Because it is a user requirement. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `ListViewItem.ItemContainerStyle` like below to achieve what you want

```
<ListView ItemsTemplate="{StaticResource parentItemTemplate}" x:Name="parent" SelectedItem="{Binding ParentSelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Whatever}">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
               <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
             </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: +1, Looks good. The only problem is when I click outside the parent ListView, the current selection gets deselected.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `InnerControl` class to achieve this.

References:

[WPF Nested ListViews - selectedValue of parent ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863541/)

Or else you can go for `RelativeSource`:

[How to access controls parent's property in a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230616/)

Hope it helps!